# OSX Touch ID not available when exiting sleep

Tags: monterey, touch-id, smart-card

For many years ago I installed/modified something in the OS to enable Smart Card support.

I am now at OS X Monterey[image: Password only, no Touch ID] and still am not able to get the possibility to use Touch ID in the popup window when I get out of sleep mode. I only have the password option.

Any idea why I get this popup window and not the normal screen for getting out of locked screen?

Comment: Did you checked [this in apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253322921) ?

Comment: Yes I also came across that forum and checked all the steps from there as I also remembered that at some point I have installed opensc. But could not find any files related to that.